# Solve $\phi(p^x)=p^{x-1}$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The question is as follows:
Solve for x: $\phi(p^x)=p^{x-1}$ where $p$ is prime. Here is what I have gotten so far: 
$$\phi(p^x)=p^x - p^{x-1} = p^{x-1}.$$
Then $$p^{x}(1-2p^{-1}) = 0.$$
So $$\frac{2}{p}=1\implies p=2.$$
Thus $$2^x - \frac{2^x}{2} = \frac{2^x}{2} \implies 2^x=2^x$$
This seems off. If this is the case, we have the solution as the set of integers which I do not think is right. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's not generally true that $p^x-p^{x-1}=p^{x-1}$

Comment: I think that solution's fine. You showed there are no solutions for odd primes and any (positive) $x$ is a solution for $p=2$.

Comment: You better write $\varphi(p^n)=p^{n-1}(p-1)$, so that $p=2$ obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi(p^k) = (p-1)p^{k-1}$

Basically, you are trying to solve

$\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}$

which is false unless $p=2$. It might be better to ask for the solution to:

$\phi(p^k) = p^{j}$ or $(p-1)p^{k-1} = p^{j}$. $\log_p$ to both sides:

$k-1 + \log(p-1)_p = j$

$\lim _{p\rightarrow\infty}(\log(p-1)_p) = 1$, so $k-1$ and $j$ will be asymptotically equal to each other.